# Monotonic Functions in Java of Comparables

Tags: java, arrays, generics, java-8

I am trying to implement an algorithm that checks if an array of comparable elements is increasing or decreasing. So far I have written this method:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isMonotonic(int[] A) {
        int store = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
            int c = Integer.compare(A[i], A[i+1]);
            if (c != 0) {
                if (c != store && store != 0)
                    return false;
                store = c;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I changed the method signature, by passing a generic method of `comparables`, but I'm struggling to implement the `compareTo` method. I am probably using the bounded generics wrong, but I'm not too sure?

My attempt:

```
public boolean Test(T[] n) 
    {
        if (n.length < 3)
            return true;

        int direction = n[0].compareTo(n[1]);
        for (int i = 1; i < n.length-1; i++){
            int step = n[i].compareTo(n[i+1]); 
            if (step == 0)
                continue;

            if (direction == 0)
                direction = step;
            else if  ( sdtep < 0 && direction > 0
                    || step > 0 && direction < 0)
                return false;

        }

        return true;                
    }
```

Comment: Don't mix generics with arrays. Generics are invariant and erased, while arrays are covariant and retained. This is a recipe for trouble. Can you use `List`s instead?

Comment: You did not show any of the problematic code, right? There are no generics here, there is no `compareTo` shown and what is `comparables`?

Comment: @Turing85 There's a challenge in the book I am studying (The Algorithm Design Manual) that requires me to use `arrays`

Comment: @luk2302 I first coded this for an array of ints, but I am now trying to find a solution using an array of <T extends Comparable<? super T>> instead of the int values

Comment: I know what you are trying but you have not shown any of that.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your attempt at a solution; showing us this version with `int[]` does not seem relevant.

Comment: Thank's for sharing, so useful!

Answer (score 3):

In order to make your method take a generic argument, change its header:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isMonotonic(T[] A)
```

You can then compare items of the array using the `Comparable::compareTo` method:

```
int c = A[i].compareTo(A[i+1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly monotone function:

```
public static boolean isMonotone(int[] a) {
    boolean monotone = true;
    if(a[0]>a[1]) {
        for(int i=0;i<(a.length-1);i++) {
            if(!(a[i]>a[i+1])){
                monotone=false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a[0]<a[1]) {
        for(int i=0;i<(a.length-1);i++) {
            if(!(a[i]<a[i+1])){
                monotone=false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a[0]==a[1]) return false;
    return monotone;
    
}
```

Comment: This code hurts my eyes. Please read up on using early-out in looped code.

Comment: I've just made some changes. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Monotone function:

```
public static boolean isMonotone(int[] a) {
    boolean monotone = true;
    int i=0;
    while(a[i]==a[i+1]) {
        i++;
    }
    if(a[i]>a[i+1]) {
        for(int j=0;j<(a.length-1);j++) {
            if(!(a[j]>=a[j+1])){
                monotone=false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a[i]<a[i+1]) {
        for(int j=0;j<(a.length-1);j++) {
            if(!(a[j]<=a[j+1])){
                monotone=false;
            }
        }
    }
    return monotone;
}
```